# communicating between angularjs and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does one facilitate communication of variables between angularjs and javascript in an HTML document.

Currently, I have a javascript that takes input from external applications and what I need to do is transfer the input, in the form of variables, to angularjs variables in order to display the information in the browser.

without going into too much detail, here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
</body>
    <script>
        var newDepth = 10;
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="GaugeController as gControl">
        // newDepth doesnt work here
        {{gControl.setDepth(newDepth)}}

        //gauge is a directive
        // used for displaying the actual gauge
        <gauge></gauge>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Make the script in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's expressions are not designed to work this way. As [the manual says](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression),

> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.
>
> Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

However, you can assign `newDepth` global to `$scope.newDepth` or `$rootScope.newDepth` in top-level controller and use it application-wide, just keep in mind that it is a hack.

Comment: so then what is the correct of communicating between angularjs and javascript?

Comment: Angular is quite opinionated framework, and such problems usually indicate a flaw in app design that should be avoided. The example with global variable isn't too demonstrative without further context, because it basically falls into 'don't do this in angular' category. But generally it is preferable to wrap all JS stuff into angular, unless there are real obstacles to do this.

Comment: This makes more sense, I guess it is better to have all the javascript code in one place rather than having it all over the place and finding "hacks" to connect the code snippets, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global variable by passing a string reference to your `setDepth` method and access the global variable there with `$window['newDepth']`.

Directly accessing `$window` inside of the expression is not allowed by Angular. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecwindow?p0=$window.alert%28%29).

Please find the demo below and in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/rgx1ggvz/).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('GaugeController', function($scope, $window) {
    console.log('global', $window.newDepth);
    this.setDepth = function(depth) {
        console.log(depth); // string name of global variable
        this.depth = $window[depth]; // access the global variable
        console.log(this.depth); // just a test to see that depth is correct
    };
    this.getDepth = function() {
        return this.depth;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var newDepth = 10;
    console.log(window.newDepth);
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="GaugeController as gControl" ng-app="myApp">
        // newDepth doesnt work here
        {{gControl.setDepth('newDepth')}}
        {{gControl.getDepth()}}
        //gauge is a directive
        // used for displaying the actual gauge
        <gauge></gauge>
    </div>
```